# TCL missing operator at _@_

Tags: operators, tcl

So I am having the following issue I am supposed to get rid of the following lsearch

```
if {[lsearch -inline ${:edges} $m$n] ne ""}
```

and i am supposed to replace it with in/ni

However when i try to that:

```
if {$m$n in ${:edges} ne ""}
```

I get the following Error Message :

```
missing operator at _@_
in expression "$m_@_$n in ${:edges} ne """
```

it should not be the biggest issue but still i cant figure it out- since i am pretty new to tcl and programming in general.

Thanks for your help

BR

Comment: $m &n  are parameters of the function

Comment: Just `$value in $list`. Need to quote, too: `"$m$n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions, unlike general Tcl, do *not* concatenate strings like that. Instead, they look for operators and so on (and the `_@_` marks *where* the expression parser was looking for an operator, in case you needed to be told that). This is trade-off to ensure that things remain syntactically unambiguous, though I can't quite remember the exact case that forces it.

There's a simple workaround though; put double quotes around the things that you want to concatenate, like this:

```
if {"$m$n" in ${:edges}}
```

(You probably don't want to chain `in` and `eq` together either; it's *legal,* but unlikely to do what you want.)